# Pass value to string imported from another module using f-string

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

This will be easier to explain with an example. Let's say I have a `settings.py` file that looks like this:

**settings.py**

```
a_string='This string should contain {value} <<< here.'
```

I then import `settings` into my `.py` file, where I have a function `mystring` that looks something like this (note the function does not work as I would like it to):

```
import settings

def mystring(value='100'):
    b_string=f'{settings.a_string}'
    return b_string

print(mystring())
# I would like this to return:
# "This string should contain 100 <<< here."
```

I have tried placing the f-string formatting inside settings.py, such as:

```
a_string="f'This string should contain {value} <<< here.'"
```

to no avail. No luck if I place it in the function or function call either.

I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I just can't see it, so any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't do that with f-strings. They are evaluated at definition time. after `a = f'...'` is executed, `a` is as "normal" as any other string

Comment: @DeepSpace That's true, but in this code, `a_string` is not an f-string, it's just a regular string containing the literal text `{value}`.

Comment: @kaya3 true, but OP specifically asked about doing this with f-string, to which I replied it's impossible (while not considering any hack involving `eval` or `exec`)

Comment: Thanks guys, the question is indeed around *f-string*, rather than other formatting ways e.g. `.format()`

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1:** use [str.format()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-format-function/):

```
b_string=settings.a_string.format(value=value)
```

**Method 2:** use eval :

```
fstr = "the value is {value}"
def func(value=100):
    b_str = eval('f"' + fstr + '"')
    return b_str
```

WARNING: Only use this method if you know what `fstr` contains. If `fstr` is something like `"open('virus.txt', 'w').write('evil')"`, your code gets vulnerable.

Comment: using `eval` just to arbitrarily be able to use an f-string is hideous and IMHO shouldn't even be listed as a considerable 'solution'

Comment: @DeepSpace but its more universal than the first method because you don't have to pass all the values.